# problems with packages

Tags: centos, software-installation, package-management, mysql

A few days ago I took a dedicated server with a centos 6 64 bits installed. 
The problem is that when trying to install sentora or cpanel-whm, it shows the 
following message:

```
Checking that minimal requirements are ok
Detected : CentOs 6 x86_64
Ok.
DB server will be mySQL
It appears that package mysql is already installed. This installer
is designed to install and configure Sentora on a clean OS installation only!

Please re-install your OS before attempting to install using this script.
```

I contacted the  support team of this company (Nocix), asking them to install centos 6 minimal, but the people working there just don't have any idea of what I'm talking about or they just don't want to do so.
I would appreciate very much if someone could give me an answer on what to do with this server. Days are running and I can't work with this server.

Comment: It is perfectly normal for your server provider to avoid (at all cost) getting into that kind of troubleshooting with you as they would need to charge you by the hour for that level of service.  Installing sentora can be quite a challenge for this and many other reasons.  You might need to uninstall certain packages but doing so may break other things and require you to add custom repositories, and so on.  That said, The last time I tested it, it was filled with **lots** of bugs and doesn't appear to have been maintained since then.

Comment: IMO, the problem is not with the packages, but with the braindead installer script that can't cope with an extremely common situation (i.e. mysql already installed - what do they expect you to do, trash any existing databases just so theirs can run?  that's insane!).  Report a bug to the sentora devs.  They'll probably ignore it, so if i were you, I'd start googling to see if someone has made a decent .rpm package for CentOs6, or an srpm for any of the rpm-based distros.  Or build a package yourself with [checkinstall](http://checkinstall.izto.org)

Comment: The deal is that I tried with c-panel whm and the same message showed up. I used the commands rpm -qa |sort |grep mysql to see what I have installed, and it gave me this mysql-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64. Then I used  sudo yum remove mysql-libs and it supposedly erased al that data, but when I tried to installed again sentora, it failed again.

Comment: you could hack their installer script so that it doesn't whinge about an existing mysql, but instead uses it.  there's absolutely no reason at all why it should force you to uninstall an existing mysql installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the packages that the install-script objects to:

```
sudo yum remove mysql
```

However, you may have more than one package which sentora objects to.  On my CentOS 6 machine, these packages are shown by

```
rpm -qa |sort |grep mysql
```

(with versions of course):

```
mysql-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64
mysql-devel-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64
mysql-libs-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64
mysql-server-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64
```

For instance, you may have only `mysql-libs`, and it might be a dependency of some other package.  I've found it (mis)used by the packages which are offered as alternatives to `sendmail` (`postfix` and `exim`).  Since I had less use for `mysql` than `sendmail`, I chose to install the latter, and remove postfix or exim.  You may find the same choices, e.g.,

```
sudo yum install sendmail
sudo yum remove mysql-libs
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas, but it didn't work. This is what happened:                                                                           [root@s92595 ~]# sudo yum remove mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: mysql
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.tzulo.com
 * extras: centos.pymesolutionsweb.com
 * updates: centos.pymesolutionsweb.com
base
extras  
updates 
updates/primary_db  
Package(s) mysql available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
Any idea what to do? thank you